# What are the paging parameters to the info method used for?

Tags: support, api-v2

As far as I can tell, there can only be one [info object](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/types/info) returned from the [info method](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info), so why does the method take page and page_size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While technically they work, they don't do much of value.    I'd keep them around for symmetry if they were the *only* method in the API which didn't need them, but they're already missing from other methods where they're nonsensical.

They'll be pulled in the next deploy, with `page` and `pagesize` on the wrapper set to 1 (if they're requested).

Comment: Uhm... does this mean the API will reject requests for `/info` that containg `page=1`? Stack.PHP's class structure expects to be able to supply pagination parameters to all methods.

Comment: @George - no it won't reject them, it will just ignore them.  Note that pagination doesn't exist on `/errors/{id}` or `filter/create` either.

Comment: Ah, okay. The users of my library should never be specifying a page number for the requests - it's just that the class keeps track of page numbers internally and by default sends the `page=1` parameter for the first request.